# GIT: Checkout to other branch without doing a commit or stage the files in the first branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am beginner at GIT. Sometimes I have a file with changes and I need to checkout to other branch. Clarify that this file exists in both branches. When I checkout git says:

1. The checkout cannot be done because you have changes not committed in the first branch and these files would be overridden
2. Other times git allows me to checkout to the second branch without doing a commit or stage the files in the first branch

Why sometimes git doesn't allow me to checkout and why sometimes does?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are conflicts between your changes and the branch, git will reasonably refuse to clobber one or the other.  The way I get around this is to stash the changes, then apply the stash (assuming I wanted my changes in the newly checked out branch):

```
> git stash save
> git checkout <brannchname>
> git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to save the uncommitted changes. You can clean your working directory, and after, you can checkout to the new branch

```
git reset --hard
git checkout theOtherBranch
```

If you want to save the changes to continue working in them after finish the work in the other branch. I prefer to commit the changes and reset later.

```
git commit -a -m "Commit to reset later"
git checkout theOtherBranch
// works in this branch and commit the changes.
git checkout theFirstBranch
git reset --mixed HEAD~1 // With this you get the working directory as the beginning.
```

If you want to translate the uncommitted changes to the other branch without save them, you can do it if there are no conflicts (Changes in the same files and lines).

```
git checkout theOtherBranch
```

If you have conflicts (your case). I think the best police is to finish the work that you are doing and commit the finished work. Then you checkout the other branch and merge the changes. There will be conflicts, but you will be allowed to fix them eventually.